# How can I apply the name of a field to an ArrayList and then add something to that ArrayList

Tags: java, field

Well, I want to import the name of a field from a CSV file and then add all the data after the name of the file into the corresponding ArrayList. I know how I can ask the class if that Field exists and if it is present but then I don't know how I can then apply the name of the field and use .add to add an element to the Array
Pls, help it's for my School project.

```
try {
    scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(filename), "UTF-8");
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
       String line = scanner.nextLine();
       String[] splitLines = line.split(",");
       Field field = Main.class.getField("splitLines[0]");
       if(ArrayList.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())){
          for (int i = 0; i < splitLines.length; i++) {
              /*this is where I want to add all of the Data to the 
                corresponding array*/
          }
        }

      }

      scanner.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found " + filename);
    }
```

I expect that I can use the first word of the CSV file and convert it to the name of the array in the class and then add all of the elements of the CSV file into the array.

Comment: Welcome to SO. And, I would recommend you to go through - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi Clemens! Can you show us an example of your CSV file?

Comment: That getField() method gets a field declared in Main.class.... that has nothing to do with your csv file?

Comment: This is for a problem that we had to do in school where we classify a sentence as discriminative towards someone. So an example of my CSV file is :                            [Races,AfricanAmerican,Hispanics,Spanish,Black,Caucasian,European,Asian,Chinese,Indian,American,Russian,Japanese,Korean] where the first word in the line is the ArrayList that I want to save all of the words after into

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reflection is not usually a good solution.  Maybe use a Map instead of named arrays.

```
var dataByName = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

Then, after you read and split a line from your file.

```
var dataList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int s = 1; s < splitLines.length; s++) {
    dataList.add(splitLines[s]);
}
dataByName.put(splitLines[0], dataList);
```

Comment: I see that is a lot better of a solution. I hoped that I can do it very simple in java to take the name of a variable and then just apply it but it seems like that a hash map was the better answer to my problem all along. thanks for the help